# Multiple actions on click - ordering issue

Tags: hyperlink, html-lists, session-storage

When the user clicks on a link to a subpage, I want to store data in sessionStorage from the current page before leaving to the next page. Then when this new page has loaded, I want to apply the sessionStorage data on this page.

What complicates things is that the link is part a collapsing menu system. Which means that this system needs to update (which is also done on click) before the page data is stored.

So essentially, the wanted execution order:

- User clicks link
- Menu system is updated
- Page data is stored
- Browser loads the new page
- Page data from the previous page loads and applies on the new page

My issue is the order in which everything is executed. I don't understand when the user clicks on the link how to control the order of when the actions are executed.

Thankful for help